# Как будить приложение и выполнять задачу через некоторые промежутки времени?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, ipad

Подскажите, как следует организовать выполнение задач в приложении через заданные промежутки времени, при этом пользователь может сворачивать приложение?

Comment: а чем этот вопрос отличается от вашего предыдущего?

Comment: Тот вопрос был направлен на выполнение непрерывной операции в фоне, а этот на периодические вызовы, на сколько я понял, дольше 10минут в фоне не поработаешь?

Comment: ну ваши врианты: 1) приложение может попроситься у системы работать на бэкграунде - не больше 10 минут, при этом система может убить ваше приложени в любой момент 2) вы можете объявить себя музыкальным проигрывателем и работать на бэкграунде сколько хотите, но вы должны играть какие то звуки, иначе эпл вас не примет 3) вы можете объявить, что ваше приложение хочет получать данные с сервера через определенные промежутки времени, тогда система вас будет "будить" для получения данных на бэкграунде.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Для того, чтобы я мог получать данные с сервера, с каким объектом мне следует разбираться, с background fetch как Вы посоветовали в том вопросе? добавьте пожалуйста Ваш ответ к вопросу, чтобы я смог выбрать его верным решением =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я уже написал в комментарии, вам нужен background mode под названием background fetch.

Делается это примерно так:

1) объявить что вы хотите делать background fetch в capabilities.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) В appDelegate объявить метод

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    //ваш код загрузки здесь

    //сообщить системе об успешности загрузки через completionHandler - это делать обязательно

    BOOL downloadSuccessful = YES;

    if(downloadSuccessful) {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    } else {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
    }
}
```

3) выставить насколько часто вы это хотите делать (обычно делается в `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];

    return YES;
}
```

Информация взята [отсюда](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-background-fetch-ios).

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а если у меня есть какие то операции на устройстве, без связи с сервером, например, нужно каждый 5 минут писать в файл время, как лучше это реализовывать? Я пробовал через UILocalNotification и application_handleActionWithIdentifier, но почему - то у меня не заходит в метод handle, а didReceiveLocalNotification на ios8.0+ не работает вообще

Comment: не уверен, но мне кажется без хака не получится. что то типа объявить себя плеером и каждые 5 минут отыгрывать какой то звук, а в это время писать время.

Comment: но за это, скорей всего, получу реджект на appstore?

Comment: читал где то статью, что именно так кто то это и реализовал. Тут вопрос в том, что если вы заявились плеером и не играете музыку, тогда будет реджект. а если будете какой то звук воспроизводить, тогда никакого криминала в этом нет.

Comment: например звук уведомления из приложения, теперь тогда новый вопрос образовывается) как будить приложение каждые 5 минут используя плеер, издавать непродолжительный звук и производить какие то записи в файл? Мне стоит оформить новый вопрос или я уже слишком много начал плодить схожих вопросов?

Comment: я бы наверно сказал новый. две хоть и связанные, но достаточно разные темы.

Comment: хотя нет. не все так сложно - если вы заявились плеером (background modes -> audio,airplay and picture in picture), то ваше приложение никогда не уходит в suspended, а всегда стоит на background и может исполнять любой код, так же как и в активном состоянии. просто не забудьте, что то делать с музыкой/звуками, чтоб иметь доказательство, что вам этот режим реально нужен.

Comment: огромное спасибо за ответ! Буду пробовать :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37769/discussion-between-dot-prox-and-max-mikheyenko).