# Как запустить функцию когда приложение закрыто

Tags: swift

У меня ечть функция которая ничего не принимает и ничего не возврощает. Внутри функции есть проверка на даты если текущий день совподает выпольняется нотификация. Когда приложение запущено все работает нормально, а если приложение закрыто и наступает следующий день функция не срабатывает надо заново запустить приложение , чтоб функция запустилась как решить проблему чтоб даже если приложение было закрыто всеровно функция работала

Comment: посмотрите комментарии в этом вопросе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508317/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8